# local daylight saving time to standard UTC time using python or R

Tags: r, pandas, time-series, timezone, dst

I have a timeseries file containing 10 years of data with daylight saving time. Time is in local time in naive format, location is St Louis, USA where multiple time zone comes in a year. A sample of the time series is here:

```
local_time          flow
11/3/12 23:30       58145400
11/4/12 0:00        58147200
11/4/12 0:30        58149000
11/4/12 1:00        58150800
11/4/12 1:30        58152600
11/4/12 1:00        58150800
11/4/12 1:30        58152600
11/4/12 2:00        58154400
11/4/12 2:30        58156200
11/4/12 3:00        58158000
11/4/12 3:30        58159800
11/4/12 4:00        58161600
11/4/12 4:30        58163400
```

if you see closely after `11/4/12 1:30        58152600` time becomes `11/4/12 1:00`. It's a sunday and the clock goes back 1 hour.

If there were no daylight saving thing then the ts should have looked this below:

```
    local_time          flow
    11/3/2012 23:30     58145400
    11/4/12 0:00        58147200
    11/4/12 0:30        58149000
    11/4/12 1:00        58150800
    11/4/12 1:30        58152600
    11/4/12 2:30        58150800
    11/4/12 3:00        58152600
    11/4/12 3:30        58154400
    11/4/12 4:00        58156200
    11/4/12 4:30        58158000
    11/4/12 5:30        58159800
    11/4/12 6:00        58161600
    11/4/12 6:30        58163400
```

Now, there are several instances like this in my original file. I want to convert the local data into UTC or CST where there will be no daylight saving time jump like the local time series data.

I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_excel(r'test_dst.xlsx, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=0)
ts_naive=df.iloc[:,0]  
ts_cst = ts_naive.dt.tz_localize('America/Chicago') # 'America/Chicago' uses CDT
```

but it gives an error: `AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from 2012-11-04 01:00:00, try using the 'ambiguous' argument`

If I use the following it gives me wrong output:

```
ts_cst = ts_naive.dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('America/Chicago')
```

because I am assigning 'UTC' time zone to a local data  which is wrong.

My ultimate goal is to remove the daylight saving timejump from the timeseries so that I can convert it into an ever increasing ts in seconds. My model can only take time in julian seconds and time series can only increase. Thanks. Here is a sample excel file: [test_dst.xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J6HoEtvtlogj8RTh4nwNI1gLWVbaHL2z/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102781316443126205856&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: Why not just `df = df.drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: That's a good idea if I want to use everything into local time. But, it will be good to convert the data into UTC or other standard time where there will be no time jump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a useful section on this in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#ambiguous-times-when-localizing), specifically the `ambiguous="infer"` argument~

```
df.local_time = pd.to_datetime(df.local_time) 
df.local_time = df.local_time.dt.tz_localize('America/Chicago', 'infer')
print(df.local_time)
print(df.local_time.dt.tz_convert("UTC"))
```

Output:

```
0    2012-11-03 23:30:00-05:00
1    2012-11-04 00:00:00-05:00
2    2012-11-04 00:30:00-05:00
3    2012-11-04 01:00:00-05:00
4    2012-11-04 01:30:00-05:00
5    2012-11-04 01:00:00-06:00
6    2012-11-04 01:30:00-06:00
7    2012-11-04 02:00:00-06:00
8    2012-11-04 02:30:00-06:00
9    2012-11-04 03:00:00-06:00
10   2012-11-04 03:30:00-06:00
11   2012-11-04 04:00:00-06:00
12   2012-11-04 04:30:00-06:00
Name: local_time, dtype: datetime64[ns, America/Chicago]

0    2012-11-04 04:30:00+00:00
1    2012-11-04 05:00:00+00:00
2    2012-11-04 05:30:00+00:00
3    2012-11-04 06:00:00+00:00
4    2012-11-04 06:30:00+00:00
5    2012-11-04 07:00:00+00:00
6    2012-11-04 07:30:00+00:00
7    2012-11-04 08:00:00+00:00
8    2012-11-04 08:30:00+00:00
9    2012-11-04 09:00:00+00:00
10   2012-11-04 09:30:00+00:00
11   2012-11-04 10:00:00+00:00
12   2012-11-04 10:30:00+00:00
Name: local_time, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```